# How to remove ESET Outlook plugins?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I've been having problem with Microsoft Outlook 2007. As i have recently been recieving this message:

[image]

I have got ESET Nod Internet Security installed like 2 months ago but then uninstalled it in about a month later since the Trial key was expired. I have then installed AVG internet security "free version" and right after installed till about 3 days ago, was totally fine, nothing wrong with it at all. Until 3 days ago, i noticed i could not send mails out from my Outlook and it somehow could receive some emails but not the other some. Everytime i open my Outlook, this message pops up and i have no idea what to do with this.

I have had a look in Program Files > then try to find Eset Nod Internet security but could not find it. I have also tried to find Add-Ins in Microsoft Outlook but could not find it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open Outlook and click the **Tools** menu you should see an option from **Trust Center** and then **Add-ins**, this should let you remove the ESET plugin and anything else that shouldn't be there.  There should be a dropdown box labeled **Manage** and a button that says **Go** at the bottom of the add-ins screen. You must select **Exchange Client Extensions** to find the ESET plugin. Click the **Go** button and look for the ESET plugin.  If you see it, remove/disable it and then restart Outlook.

Comment: Hi Mr.Warmth, Thanks so much for your answer, it worked and i now got rid of the stupid message. Although now i wanna know how to set it to run in the background. Like my work place, even the Microsoft outlook is closed, it's still able to receive emails or reminders. I have TuneUp 2011 programme which allow me to set programmes to run in the background. I have set outlook to run at startup but i've restarted serveral times and try to email to myself and it didn't seem to receive any email without having have to open the Microsoft outlook first to receive email. Is there anyway how to do that?

Comment: This [guide from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251340) will help you setup Outlook 2007 to run minimized when your computer starts up so it's always receiving email in the background. Afterwards you can right-click on your Outlook icon in the system tray and select `Hide when minimized` if you don't want Outlook showing in the taskbar while minimized.

Answer (score 0):

After you have found Eset you just need to unselected the check box and then you are warm and dry press ok restart Outlook.

Comment: True, but you can guide him to where the OP has to go to find the setting.